# Cannot change shortcut in Zen Coding?

Tags: html, plugins

I recently installed the plugin Zen Coding for Notepad++. I want to change the shortcut for "Expand Abbreviation" (below) from CTRL+E to Tab

[image]

However when going to settings-shortcut mapper, this shortcut doesn't appear to exist in the plugin commands (below). Also I can't find it in the main list of shortcuts either

[image]

The shortcut does work (CTRL+E), however I'd prefer tab as it's quicker. Any ideas where/how I can change this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Locate and open the "zen coding.js" file in your directory:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\NppScripting\includes\Zen Coding.js**
On line 7998 edit:
addMenuItem('Expand Abbreviation', 'expand_abbreviation', 'Ctrl+E');
Change 'Ctrl+E' to whatever you want.